# Ubuntu Linux server - set file permissions for VirtualBox shared folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, permissions

I have Ubuntu server with Apache 2, PHP, and various DBMSs running in VirtualBox on my Mac host for my web development work.  To easily create/edit the files I'm working on, I mounted a directory from my Mac host via the VirtualBox shared directory feature to `/var/www/`. Every file I create on my Mac host has the following permissions on the on the Server: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6 2011-07-30 01:27 test`.

The problem is that most PHP scripts/frameworks/etc. need *write access* to some files.  It is extremely annoying to have to *chmod* every new file/directory that needs write access.  Is there a way to set the correct permissions for the files/directories automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set some mounting options while mounting your the shared folder on the guest OS - here are the available options:

> http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/mount.vboxsf.8.html

There are many solutions to your problem:

- To make the files seen as owned by your VirtualBox user's uid and gid (using the uid and gid mounting options).
- To override the mode of all files/directories using dmode and fmode options.
- To change the umask on your host to a less restrictive mask.

I usually prefer the first option. In your case the entry to the `/etc/fstab` file should look like this:

```
dev /var/www vboxsf umask=0022,gid=33,uid=33
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used VirtualBox to run LAMP stacks within my Ubuntu Host for a few years and to share directories with Macintosh or Windows OSs, without running into this problem, I've found that Samba is the easiest solution.

With Samba you can set-up a default permission mask to use on all new files or folders created in the shared folder. There is also a great Webmin plugin that makes Samba administration a breeze.

Take a look here http://www.webmin.com/samba-howto.html